# Generating evalable python code: all combinations of functions in disjunctive normal form

Tags: python, eval

```
(A,B,C) = (100, 200, 300)

def f1(p): return p+50 
def f2(p): return p*1.5 
def f3(p): return p*p 

vars_ = (A,B,C)
funcs_ = [f1, f2, f3]
logic_ = ["and","or"]
vol_lmt_ = [200, 300]
op_ = [">","<","="]
```

I want generate the assert code string for eval() to test the validity, take below one for example:

```
"f1(A)>200 and f1(B)>200 and f1(C)>200"                             # True
 -^-------------^-------------^------------: funcs_
 ----^-------------^-------------^---------: vars_
 ------^-------------^-------------^-------: op_
 --------^-------------^-------------^-----: vol_lmt_        
 ------------^-------------^---------------: logic_
```

My questions are:

1. how to generate the code string I wanted based on those vars above?
2. how to enumerate all test logic possibility for above `(A,B,C)`? For example:

   `"f1(A)>200 and f1(B)>200 and f1(C)>200"`
   `"f1(A)<300 and f2(B)=200 or f3(C)>200"`
3. is it possible to replace the the name of function to the list entry when generate the code?

   `"f(A)>200 and f1(B)>200 and f1(C)>200"`

   To

   `"funcs_[0](A)>200 and funcs_[0](B)>200 and funcs_[0](C)>200"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can summaries what you are trying to do (using python2 syntax):

```
import itertools

arguments = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
funcs_ = [f1, f2, f3, f4]
logic_ = ["and","or"]
op_ = [">","<","="]
vol_lmt_ = [200, 300]

num_func = len(funcs_)

assert num_func == len(arguments), ("The number of argument should be the same as "
                                    "the number of function.")

operands = itertools.product(["funcs_[%d]" % i for i in range(num_func)],
                             arguments,
                             op_,
                             vol_lmt_)

def comp(operands):
    templ = "{func}({arg}){op}{val}"
    for operand in operands:
        yield templ.format(func=operand[0], arg=operand[1],
                           op=operand[2], val=operand[3])

new_operands = map(comp, itertools.tee(operands, num_func))

# construct the argument to pass to itertools.product.
args = []
for operand in new_operands:
    args.append(operand)
    args.append(logic_)

args.pop() # Remove the last logic operator.

res = itertools.product(*args)

print " ".join(res.next())
# funcs_[0](A)>200 and funcs_[0](A)>200 and funcs_[0](A)>200 and funcs_[0](A)>200

...
```

In this method i just cheated by replacing `vars_` with ('A', 'B', 'C'). beside that i think it should work.

---

If you don't like my way of cheating by hard coding the the `vars_` list and the `funcs_` name you can get the name of your variable from the [globals](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals) dictionary something like this:

```
def get_name(obj):
    """Get the name of an object (variable) from the globals dict.

    Argument:
       - obj : The variable that we want to get the name of. 

    Return:
       - A string representing the name of the object if it was found else return None.

    """

    for name, value in globals().items():
         if value is obj:
             return name
```

Comment: Since it is unclear whether Bobby is using Python 2 or Python 3, it is worth noting that in the latter `print find_names(a)[0]` needs to be spelled `print(find_names(a)[0])`, and that `f.func_name` needs to be spelled `f.__name__`.

Comment: @lvc: yes that true i just add a specification that i did this using python2.6 :)

Comment: @mouad, thanks for your code, I need time to understand it -_-b, more, if the funcs_ is a list of lambda functions, is that code still workable? that is where my question 3 came from.

Comment: @user478514: hmmm good question no it will not work, i will update my answer to include this case soon :)

Comment: @mouad, I just found another problem if you changed the vars_ from `('A', 'B', 'C')` to `('A', 'B', 'C','D')`, the number of tee and the 2nd product() need to be rewitten. Any suggestion?

Comment: @user478514: nice :) i just edited my answer hope this time it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to taking the outer/cartesian product, "summing" across the "var" dimension, and interspersing those with the outer product of logic operators. You can use `itertools.product` or just the normal list comprehensions. **The following will work for any number of variables, functions, comparators, logic operators, and numeric thresholds. It is also easily extensible if you choose to make more complicated expressions**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pprint import pprint as pp
from itertools import *

VARS = 'XYZ'
FUNCS = range(2)
COMPARE = '><='
LOGIC = ['and', 'or']
NUMS = [200, 300]

def listJoin(iter):
    return sum(map(list,iter), [])

terms = [
    [
         'func[{func}]({var}){compare}{num}'.format(func=func, var=var, compare=compare, num=num)
         for var in VARS
    ]
    for func in FUNCS
    for compare in COMPARE
    for num in NUMS
]

def intersperse(iter, joiners):
    iter = list(iter)
    for tokens in product(*(joiners for _ in iter[:-1])):
        yield ' '.join(listJoin(zip(iter,tokens))+[iter[-1]])

formulas = listJoin(intersperse(t, LOGIC) for t in terms)

pp(formulas)
```

Result:

```
['func[0](X)>200 and func[0](Y)>200 and func[0](Z)>200',                                                                                               
 'func[0](X)>200 and func[0](Y)>200 or func[0](Z)>200',
 'func[0](X)>200 or func[0](Y)>200 and func[0](Z)>200',
 'func[0](X)>200 or func[0](Y)>200 or func[0](Z)>200',
 'func[0](X)>300 and func[0](Y)>300 and func[0](Z)>300',
 'func[0](X)>300 and func[0](Y)>300 or func[0](Z)>300',
 'func[0](X)>300 or func[0](Y)>300 and func[0](Z)>300',
 'func[0](X)>300 or func[0](Y)>300 or func[0](Z)>300',
 'func[0](X)<200 and func[0](Y)<200 and func[0](Z)<200',
 'func[0](X)<200 and func[0](Y)<200 or func[0](Z)<200',
 'func[0](X)<200 or func[0](Y)<200 and func[0](Z)<200',
 'func[0](X)<200 or func[0](Y)<200 or func[0](Z)<200',
 'func[0](X)<300 and func[0](Y)<300 and func[0](Z)<300',
 'func[0](X)<300 and func[0](Y)<300 or func[0](Z)<300',
 'func[0](X)<300 or func[0](Y)<300 and func[0](Z)<300',
 'func[0](X)<300 or func[0](Y)<300 or func[0](Z)<300',
 'func[0](X)=200 and func[0](Y)=200 and func[0](Z)=200',
 'func[0](X)=200 and func[0](Y)=200 or func[0](Z)=200',
 'func[0](X)=200 or func[0](Y)=200 and func[0](Z)=200',
 'func[0](X)=200 or func[0](Y)=200 or func[0](Z)=200',
 'func[0](X)=300 and func[0](Y)=300 and func[0](Z)=300',
 'func[0](X)=300 and func[0](Y)=300 or func[0](Z)=300',
 'func[0](X)=300 or func[0](Y)=300 and func[0](Z)=300',
 'func[0](X)=300 or func[0](Y)=300 or func[0](Z)=300',
 'func[1](X)>200 and func[1](Y)>200 and func[1](Z)>200',
 'func[1](X)>200 and func[1](Y)>200 or func[1](Z)>200',
 'func[1](X)>200 or func[1](Y)>200 and func[1](Z)>200',
 'func[1](X)>200 or func[1](Y)>200 or func[1](Z)>200',
 'func[1](X)>300 and func[1](Y)>300 and func[1](Z)>300',
 'func[1](X)>300 and func[1](Y)>300 or func[1](Z)>300',
 'func[1](X)>300 or func[1](Y)>300 and func[1](Z)>300',
 'func[1](X)>300 or func[1](Y)>300 or func[1](Z)>300',
 'func[1](X)<200 and func[1](Y)<200 and func[1](Z)<200',
 'func[1](X)<200 and func[1](Y)<200 or func[1](Z)<200',
 'func[1](X)<200 or func[1](Y)<200 and func[1](Z)<200',
 'func[1](X)<200 or func[1](Y)<200 or func[1](Z)<200',
 'func[1](X)<300 and func[1](Y)<300 and func[1](Z)<300',
 'func[1](X)<300 and func[1](Y)<300 or func[1](Z)<300',
 'func[1](X)<300 or func[1](Y)<300 and func[1](Z)<300',
 'func[1](X)<300 or func[1](Y)<300 or func[1](Z)<300',
 'func[1](X)=200 and func[1](Y)=200 and func[1](Z)=200',
 'func[1](X)=200 and func[1](Y)=200 or func[1](Z)=200',
 'func[1](X)=200 or func[1](Y)=200 and func[1](Z)=200',
 'func[1](X)=200 or func[1](Y)=200 or func[1](Z)=200',
 'func[1](X)=300 and func[1](Y)=300 and func[1](Z)=300',
 'func[1](X)=300 and func[1](Y)=300 or func[1](Z)=300',
 'func[1](X)=300 or func[1](Y)=300 and func[1](Z)=300',
 'func[1](X)=300 or func[1](Y)=300 or func[1](Z)=300']
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would start by saying eval is a bad idea.There is always another way to do it.

Answer to your question:

Question 1:

Function name,

You can get using f.func_name.

Variable name,

Not so simple,but this should work,

```
import gc, sys

def find_names(obj):
    frame = sys._getframe()
    for frame in iter(lambda: frame.f_back, None):
        frame.f_locals
    result = []
    for referrer in gc.get_referrers(obj):
        if isinstance(referrer, dict):
            for k, v in referrer.iteritems():
                if v is obj:
                    result.append(k)
    return result

a = 97
print find_names(a)[0]
```

It doesn't matter if it returns the wrong name since their value will be equal.

The operator and vol_limit is easily generated.

2nd Question.

No obvious solution out of mind. Iterate through all of them?

3rd Question.

Yes it is possible.
Check out [Decorators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators).